# Marking an element with applied plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, jquery-plugins

How would you mark an element to which a plugin has been applied? Suppose that I have this html:

```
    <a href="..." id="special-link">Link</a>
```

And in javascript, I would "apply a plugin"

```
    $("#special-link").selectify();
```

Later I would like to know whether #special-link is already selectify-ied. I can think of these possibilities:

1. **Add a class to the element.** You can gather all elements with selectify simply by calling $(".selectified") and it is also easy to check whether an element has the plugin applied by calling $("elem").hasClass("selectified"). A drawback I can think of is that you're using CSS (=design) to store an info.
2. **Set a data- value.** It is a bit more difficult to find all elements with the selectify plugin applied, however it is "cleaner" solution in a way because you're not using CSS class to store an information
3. **The plugin itself takes care of remembering the elements.** This sounds like the best solution. However, you, as the creator of a plugin have to take care of keeping track of all the elements and putting them in a list. In case you have some sort "destroy" method, you would also have to remember to remove them from a list.

Which one do you think is the best solution? Can you think of any other advantages/disadvantages of the above mentioned methods?

Comment: jQuery plugins (the better ones) normally use classes for styling additions and store a code instance in the elements `data` (not `data-` attributes).

Answer (score 0):

jQuery plugins (the better ones) normally use classes only for styling additions and they store a *code instance* in the elements `data` (not `data-` attributes).

But, why not simply use an existing system for creating jQuery plugins, like the [jQuery UI plugin Widget Factory](http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/stateful-plugins-with-widget-factory/)

They do the heavy lifting for you :)